# British [a] = American [ɑ] in certain words

Tags: american-english, british-english, vowels

There is a large group of words in which /a/ is pronounced [a] or [æː] in most American and some British dialects, but [ɑː] in most British dialects; this group includes *past*, *can’t*, *fast*, etc. This is the [BATH vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set).

But there is a much smaller group of words where the relationship is reversed: (all?) British dialects have [a], while American dialects have [ɑː]. This group includes words like *tacos* and *pasta*. This vowel does not seem to be covered in any of the normal lexical sets.

The BrEng and AmEng pronunciations of [*pasta*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/pasta) and *[taco](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/taco)* can be heard on the Cambridge Dictionary website for anyone who is curious.

What is the reason behind this reverse distribution?

Comment: These are all Spanish/Italian words. I don't think I've ever seen a good answer to this question. One thing to note is that the Italian dialects that Americans and Brits typically hear may not be the same, and not all Italian dialects pronounce their "a"s the same.

Comment: Interesting that the pronunciations of *pasta* and *pastor* are apparently swapped on the different sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: Shel Silversteen wrote a story about someone who bought an aunt eater as a pet instead of an ant eater, with desastrous consequences.

Comment: @PeterShor I don't think that answers it. From the context on that page, it looks like they're saying that /a/ has only one variant in Neapolitan, which always counts among the open vowels (unlike /e/ and /o/, which have both open and closed variants). Compare /i/, which is listed as “always closed”. The IPA symbol used there is /a/, which is the same as in standard Italian (as opposed to the /ɑ/ in _father_). I don't think it's saying that /a/ is [ɑ] in Neapolitan (though I freely admit I don't know much about Neapolitan, and it may well be that it _is_ actually [ɑ].)

Comment: @user214063 As it was, your question appeared under-researched and was in danger of being closed as such. I've added some additional details and fleshed out the premise assumed as well as adding a source to show explicitly why this is in fact an excellent question.

Comment: @Janus: you're right ... I deleted my comment when I realized that this didn't really give the answer. Now that you've addressed it, it would be nice if I could restore it. But it would be good if an Italian could tell us whether /a/'s are pronounced slightly differently in Sicilian and/or Neapolitan (which are the dialects of Italian that Italian immigrants most likely spoke.

Comment: Who ya gonna trust? Yanks eat more tacos and pasta than Brits. QED. ;-)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Not quite, because most North Americans have a phonemic /r/ in the coda, so it's not optional for us and therefore when you guys leave it off we hear a different phoneme although you do not. It's more like flipping *Pastor Andy* for *Pasta Randy*, which is Chef Randolph's famous aphrodesiac entry at the annual Pastarama Bake-Off at the Baptists' Pastorama Jubilee. :)

Comment: West Coast Americans are like this vs East Coast Americans with regard to the /a/ ~ /ɔ/ distinction. I grew up in Illinois, where they're distinct: _Dawn/Don_ and _hauler/holler_ are different. Now I live in Washington state, and they're not different here. This is a problem even for linguists, since they can pronounce them either way but if they don't learn them natively, they don't know which words are sposta have /ɔ/, since it doesn't exist in their dialect. And it's the same reason I can't speak RP; I don't know which words are sposta have /ɑː/ because it doesn't exist in my dialect.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of differences between which phonetic allophones BrE and AmE select for the perceived /ɑ/ phoneme, partly because AmE has no phonemic length but BrE does, partly because they have an [a] vowel that we do not and which we may hear as [æ].

The Brits do this even with words whose origins lies well beyond the old Roman Empire.

Last week during [Japanese Prime Minister Shinzō Abe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinz%C5%8D_Abe)’s historic visit to the Pearl Harbor, I was stunned to hear the BBC pronounce that gentleman’s surname [ˈæbeɪ].  This is quite close to how one says the English word *abbey* [ˈæbiʲ].

This wasn’t just one newscaster alone, either, but several.  I think I am not alone in finding this bizarre, as our asker’s question illustrates. And I think I now finally know the answer.

*Abe* is simply /ɑbe/ in Japanese.  To an American, that becomes [ˈɑbeɪ], with the only modification an end-of-word off-glide /j/ for the /e/ vowel. To us, *can* and *Khan* are a minimal pair between /kæn/ and /kɑn/.

The common trait of many speakers of Southern British English to hear one thing but pronounce another even though it is different tells me that these must be allophones in the same phonemic bucked to them ***but not so to us***.  The most likely culprit here is the [*trap–bath* split*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8a%E2%9F%A9#Trap.E2.80.93bath_split) where /æ/ becomes for them /ɑː/.

The linked Wikipedia article also mentions that the so-called “short A” of *bath*, which we use [æ] for, is often [a ~ a̠] in the North but [ɑː] in the South.
Notice how none of those is our own [æ].  Our own ears are like to throw all of [ɑ ~ a ~ ɐ] into /ɑ/ for we have no [a] at all.

So I think what’s happening is that the British are reproducing phonemic /ɑ/ as [a] or [æ] because it has no long marker for them as *arbor* or *father* would.  We don’t do phonemic vowel length in North America, so we are not conditioned to make that sort of phonetic swap.

Because words like *taco* have no length marker as a hypothetical *tarco* would, they choose a short vowel there, and for them that’s if not exactly an [æ], at least something we perceive as such. I’m sure they don’t even realize they are doing this.

I think *at all* is a good illustration of this, because the unstressed /æ/ in *at* becomes [ɐ] or [ə]. So these Brits hear something they perceive as [ɐ] and therefore render as [æ] under stress, as in *apple*.

American speakers never do this, so it is bizarre for us to hear.

Comment: I don't think this quite holds water as an explanation. There are dialects in BrE where (ignoring length) the TRAP and BATH vowels are both [a], while the FATHER vowel is [ɑ]; and there are dialects where TRAP is [a], BATH/FATHER [ɑ]. Note that _bath_ is [baθ] (short vowel) in the former, but [bɑːθ] (long vowel) in the latter—but even in the latter, _pasta_ has the TRAP vowel, not the BATH vowel, whereas in AmE it has the FATHER vowel. So do we just consider this another lexical set that isn't included in Wells’ list (like the [ɑ ~ eɪ] correspondence in _tomato_)? And why does the vowel in ->

Comment: -> these particular words differ from the multitude of words that have the TRAP, BATH, and FATHER vowels?

Comment: @Mark Don Quixote is normally pronounced [dɒn kiˈ(h)əʊti] in British as well when talking about the character in the book, but usually [dɒn ˈkwɪksət] when referring to the abstracted character type (I’ve never heard [dɒn ˈkwɪksəʊt] like you describe). And conversely, I’ve only ever heard _quixotic_ pronounced [kiˈəʊtɪk] by Brits, never Americans.

Comment: @Janus Absolutely correct. My memory was faulty. I've fixed my error by revising my comment below. The teacher was doing advanced studies in Cervantes when he wasn't substitute-teaching brats like us. Despite the strange-to-us pronunciation, he was fascinating and a refreshing break from the usual drivel we were being taught at the time. Americans do say "kwicksotic," and I've never heard it pronounced any other way. Thank you for your comments and analysis.

Comment: In American English, there is at least an attempt in many cases to pronounce "foreign" words "correctly" (as they're pronounced in their country of origin), while the Brits tend to Anglicize foreign words. We had a British substitute teacher whose expertise was Cervantes' *Don "KWICKS-et,"* which made us all snicker. We were rude children but familiar with the story of *Don "Kee-HOH-tay."* This is a gross generalization, of course, but perhaps this tendency is left over from Britain's empire-building era, imposing British pronunciations on "foreign" words? Brilliant answer and great comments!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There must be some reason why Brits think that they're saying /abe/ the way they hear it when they use the vowel from *cat* even thougjt ot has the father vowel. If it's not a mismapping of allophones then I wonder what it is.

Comment: @tchrist BrE [ɑː] tends to be further back than its AmE counterpart, which is slightly more centralised; conversely, BrE [a] is much more centralised than AmE [æ]. The Japanese vowel is usually a very central [ä], so regardless of length (which, after all, is only limitedly phonemic), both BrE and AmE seem to choose the closest equivalent available, the most centralised open vowel in the inventory.

Comment: First you talk about *AmE* and *BrE*, but then you talk about *they* and *we*. Who's *they*? Who's *we*?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Spanish has the same centralized [ä] for /a/ so if Japanese does too, that could explain all of *Abe, taco, macho*. Thing is I feel like BrE speakers choosing the TRAP vowel think they are saying the same thing as AmE speakers are saying with the FATHER vowel but Americans don't see it that way. How come we perceive them not to be saying the same vowel but they do not?

Comment: I'm originally a Brit who grew up in a long vowel neck of the woods (Bath with a long drawn out 'a'). I get a lot of grief from my American friends for saying Taco with a short 'a'. I say the word how I see it. I don't know Spanish, so it looks like Taco with a short a to me.

Comment: @ukayer Does that mean you pronounce *halo* as though it were *hallow*?  I guess we learn these words by ear first not by eye here, which means we know how they're really said, and our phonology is modified. The English tendency to see a written *a* but pronounce it as /æ/  (like *cat*) is just as crazy as seeing a written *e* but pronouncing it as /i/ (like *me*), or a written *o* but pronouncing it as  /u/ (like *do*), which is a pretty perverse chain-shift of what those letters were created for, since anybody else using the Latin alphabet leaves them alone. Learning another language helps.

Comment: halo as in "hay"-low but of course halogen as in "hallow"-gen. I certainly didn't learn taco by hearing it and to my eye always looks like "tack"-o not t-"ahh"-co. Borrowing words from a different language is always interesting, what about the word "fillet" as in "fill"-it which is very different than the French work "filet" as in fill-A?

Comment: @ukayer Name an English word that ends with the letters *-aco* or *-acho* where that A has the vowel from *cat*. Notice anything interesting here? There's a good lesson to be learnt from this pattern if you've got a sharp enough eye to spot it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The funny thing here is that you aren't supposed to be able to have checked vowels in open syllables. Hence the doubled consonant in *hallow* compared with *halo*. That’s why we spell *whacko* and *tobacco* with an extra consonant, or even *patchouli*. But it’s like BrE speakers didn’t get that memo when they put checked not open vowels in *Abe, taco, nacho*. Seems like some sort of butchery (not boucherie) of how orthography is expected to reflect phonology for checked vowels versus open ones.

Comment: @tchrist There are other checked vowels in (stressed) open syllables, like words ending in _-atic_. I don't actually know if such words are generally considered to have ambisyllabic consonants, but that would be one way to get past the issue (_taco_ etc. would then be ambisyllabic as well, I suppose).

Comment: @tchrist Randomly, another example just popped up on telly, this one actually spelled with a geminate: _Chewbacca_.